# Storing an identifying value to be used in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm planning to build a stored procedure that will insert rows into many different tables.

In each insert I need to use the same identifying value for each table, but the value must increase from one invocation of the stored procedure to the next.

How can I achieve this using T-SQL ?

Comment: *"What is the best option I can use?"* What is best isn't an on-topic question for SO; it'll probably generate opinion-based answers which isn't what SO is for. Show us what you've tried, and explain why you feel it isn't an efficient solution and others can contribute alternative methods.

Comment: I need to keep track of the ID Field in order to be synchronized between the target tables. The only issue is that the stored procedure can be called at any moment from other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a sequence in your case. And within your stored procedure, you can simply read the value from the sequence object using select next value for..

```
  -- Creating a sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NewCounter
AS INT
START WITH 0
INCREMENT BY 3
MAXVALUE 100000
CYCLE;

--Selecting the next value
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.NewCounter

-- Restarting the sequence
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.NewCounter
RESTART WITH 7
```

Comment: I ended up using a sequence. It solved my problem.